# How to 'unlock' table header rows in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word-2003

I have a Microsoft word 2003 document that contains a table. I have to edit the text in the header row of that table. However, I can't select it, nor select any text in these header cells.

Any idea how to 'unprotect' that table header row?

Answer (score 2):

Is the document as a whole protected, perhaps for forms? It's possible to design a form to look very much like a normal document, but with only specific parts editable.

If that's not it, are you sure you're on the first page of the table? If the table has "heading rows repeat" turned on, the first row will show up at the top of every page, but will only be editable on the first page.

If neither of those suggestions help, you'll probably need to contact the person who originally wrote the document.

Answer (score 1):

This is old but still relevant.  If you've split your table over several pages, you'll not be able to edit the header of the table on the split pages.  You'll need to goto the first page your table starts on and then you can edit the headers.